# Using the new GIS for a web app and having issues with getting data

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I have a project in Firebase, I currently use the Angular Fire library, and have the AngularFireAuth for sign in. This is all working well.

The next feature I am trying to implement is sending emails once a form has been submitted with certain criteria. I would like to get this set up similar to how this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) for Wordpress is done. To that end, I have a page that gets a token from Google for an account that the user chooses. I moved the functions that make the calls to the api into my cloud functions as oncall functions. So far, I can get a response from them, but none of the actual data from the api is returning.

I am using their sample of getting calendar events just to make a connection and response work.

I used this guide for the code: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#library_quick_reference

I followed several suggestions for the cloud functions until this point.

Component that calls the Cloud functions:

```
async loadCalendar() {
    await this.fns.httpsCallable('loadCalendar')({ accessToken: this.access_token })
.subscribe(async result => {
      console.log('result', result);
    });
  }
```

This is my cloud function:

```
exports.loadCalendar = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log('Manual Logging: loadCalendar started');
  console.log('Data: ' +data);
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
  const https = require('https');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get({
      hostname: 'googleapis.com',
      path: '/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events',
      headers: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        'Authorization': 'Bearer data.accessToken',
      },
    }).on('response', (result: any) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
  }).then((result) => {
    // return 'You Reached the Cloud Function';
    return result;
  });
});
```

Like I mentioned, I can get any result I hard code in, like the "You reached the cloud function" but when I return the actual result from the Google api, I am getting FirebaseError: INTERNAL and then a very long list of items with line references.

Also, if anyone can point me to a better guide for the new GIS, that would be great, as it is now, I don't have anything to guide me once I actually try to send emails.